# Fetch Column Values From a datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using a datatable. In that I have column values ReminderDate(date) and ID(int). 
If Today's date is equal to ReminderDate I need to fetch all rows that has today's date as ReminderDate and respective ID of the row.
I tried few methods using queries connected to the database. Now I would like to know if there's a method to fetch data without using queries.

I am trying to acheive something like this

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows){
if(row["ReminderDate"].ToString()){
    return row["ID"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The sole way of interacting with any kind of relational databases is though queries. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i think the OP is alluding to something called a. ORM like Entity Framework or Dapper - but hey i'm just guessing because the question is too vague for me..

Comment: Maybe, already flagged as unclear until clarification is done. Of course, ORMs just end up submitting queries themselves too, sometimes exposing that to the user.

Comment: DataTable todayTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("ReminderDate").Date == DateTime.Now().Date).CopyToDataTable();